# How can I use ExtJs4 Component again?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I ask many Question, but Anybody no answer me...

please answer this question..

Hi, i'm novice at Extjs4

I use extjs4,

I make one component, like this

```
var child1 = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                    xtype : 'panel',
                    title : 'child1',
                    html : 'child1'
                });
```

and, I use this to Window 1, like this

```
var win1 = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                    title : 'window1',
                    height : 200,
                    width : 400,
                    layout : 'fit',
                    items : child1
                }).show();
```

and I wanna use 'child1', another window, like this

```
var win2 = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', { // setting
            height : 200,
            width : 200,
            layout : 'fit',
            title : 'window2',
            items : child1
        }).show();
```

but this is wrong Code.

it is just see in Window2.

but I wanna use 'child1' both win1 and win2...

How can i do that?, Thanks!

Comment: Please remove etxjs/extj4// from your question titles (from all of them). You don't need to repeat tags in the title

Comment: Justin has the correct answer below, here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/N7Lkg/ The reason why your example didnt work is because the DOM for the panel was actually moved into window1 DOM and then the same panel DOM was moved again to the inside of window 2 ... instead you had to create two instances of the same DOM to show in two separate floating windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use re-use a component, create a view and assign an alias using widget.*

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Child1', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.child1',
    html: 'child1'
});
```

Then, when you create your window you can reference by xtype.

```
var win1 = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title : 'window1',
    height : 200,
    width : 400,
    layout : 'fit',
    items : [{ xtype: 'child1'}]
}).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both them just fine. But items is array - so you need to change it to `items: [ child1 ]`